# No sound on Windows 7 Professional x64

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, sound-card

I have an M-Audio Audiophile 2496 with the latest drivers installed. Every once in a while, unpredictably, audio stops working. I usually work around this by rebooting and everything goes back to normal. Here are the symptoms:

- When trying to play music in iTunes the time stays at 0:00
- When trying to play music on Google Music the time stays at 0:00
- When trying to play videos or music in VLC, the time will proceed normally. I only get video, no audio.

I found [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/help/no-sound-in-windows) in my attempt to fix the problem. The audio playback test says that my speakers are unplugged. This makes no sense because restarting my computer doesn't plug my speakers back in. I think it must be referring to my motherboard's sound card. The fixit program wants to use "High Definition Audio Device" and doesn't give me an option for the Audiophile.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Has anybody experienced this issue / does anybody know a fix?

**EDIT:** I am not sure if this is the cause because this is only a correlation and not a causal link. Whenever I reboot my computer to fix the sound the flash update dialog pops up. I just rebooted my computer and the update dialog came up again.

Comment: what does the driver panel of the M-Audio say? I used to have similar problems, and they were caused by noise in the power lines (eg turning on a light switch) somehow messing up the usb connection between my Audiophile and the pc.

Comment: I'll check that next time, but my Audiophile is a PCI card.

Comment: Do you need the onboard sound? If not, try disabling it in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a similar experience. It is from Egosys Sound Card Prodigy HD2, and has much in common, the manufacturer simply stopped supporting the WDM, ASIO sound card driver standards and it runs only WASAPI ... others not, nor test the sound and adjust the speaker. If you try it on another OS, like Windows XP, and 64-bit it runs, but on Vista I had problems arise during standby, the sound will not start, and with Windows 7 64-bit or already running sound in games direct sound and therefore no YouTube, etc.

For this card there is excellent output quality and the possibility to change OPAM operational amplifier at the output of the card, resulting in excellent audio quality. There are two options for adding an additional sound card (even cheaper for Windows) as a secondary card. Or wait until the manufacturer of the card makes an effort to provide finished quality drivers for Windows 7 64-bit. The experience in Linux 64-bit is excellent, everything is running at 100 percent, sound quality, viewer, YouTube, video, playback, that's because the Linux developers can make it happen. The Prodigy HD2 sound card has the Envy 1720/24 audio chipset and it runs everything.